# Can I use Sql Server and Visual Studio Express versions to create a WF app?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I want to make a Workflow 4 application, but I'm not sure if I need any other software other than the express versions of Visual Studio (for code) and Sql Server (for the persistence store)?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is *any* version of Visual Studio 2010 to create a WF4 application.  Express versions can be used to create a commercial product, so you don't even need to buy an MSDN subscription.

You can use any SKU of Sql Server (I believe 2005 is the earliest version, but that may be incorrect) for your store using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore, and you can create your own InstanceStore implementation to store your workflow instances anywhere.

Comment: You are correct in SQL Server 2005 being the lowest version supported with the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.